# Nodejs ignora request POST feita pelo Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, http, cors

Contexto:

Estou usando uma maquina virtual , `ng serve` está rodando na porta 4200, e o nodejs na porta 8024, quando tento enviar dados para o servidor nada acontece, a parte do angular aparentemente não apresenta erros. Quando uso o `postman` para enviar uma request (vinda do sistema fora da maquina virtual), não ocorre nenhum problema.

Já testei a url via postman, habilitei o `CORS` e nada funciona.

App.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
const project = require('./controllers/ProjectController');
const auth = require('./controllers/AuthController');
const task = require('./controllers/TaskController');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');

app.use(cors());
app.options('*', cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

app.use(auth);
app.use(project);
app.use(task);

module.exports = app;
```

URL que foi usada:

```
router.post('/register',(req,res) =>{
    console.log('teste'); //nunca é ativada
    let salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
    let hashedPassword = bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, salt);
    var user = {
        id:0,
        login:req.body.login,
        name:req.body.name,
        role:'user',
        password:hashedPassword
    }

    let query = 'insert into user set ?';
    db.query(query,user,(err)=>{
        if(err){
            res.sendStatus(400);
            throw err;
        }else{
            res.sendStatus(201);
        }
    })
})
```

Trecho usado no Angular :

```
  registerUser(user: User) {
    console.log(user); // sempre funciona sem erros
    const body = new HttpParams()
      .set('login', user.login)
      .set('password', user.password)
      .set('name', user.name);

    return this.http.post(this.url,
      body.toString(),
      {
        headers: new HttpHeaders()
          .set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
      }
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenta usar dessa forma

```
salvar(user: User): Promise<User> {
    return this.http.post(this.url, user)
      .toPromise()
      .then(usuarioSalvo=> usuarioSalvo.json())
      .catch(erro => {
        return Promise.reject(`Erro ao salvar o user: ` + erro);
      });
  }
```

Quando salvar com sucesso vai cair no then, se tive retornando da API o usuário salvo, logo é só pegar ele dentro do then.

Caso dê erro, vai cair no catch(), daí é só tratar os erros ou usar o usuário salvo.